# SVN ADD files i do not want

Tags: svn, addition

Instead of using the exclude file from SVN i try to add in the svn only the file i want in the following way...

```
>find . | egrep -v ".old|.obsolete|.~|.wmv|.pyc|.done|.lock|.svn" | xargs svn add
```

still after the command i have some .wmv added in the SVN

```
>svn status | grep ".wmv"
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial4.wmv
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial5.wmv
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial6.wmv
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial1.wmv
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial2.wmv
A       doc/www/home/videos/Tutorial3.wmv
```

printing on a file the result of the find does not contain thoose files

```
find . | egrep -v ".old|.obsolete|.~|.wmv|.pyc|.done|.lock|.svn" > temp.txt
```

Does anyone know why they are anyway added to my SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn add` is recursive by default, that is `svn add doc/www/home/videos` will add all `*.wmv` files. To avoid this behavior try something like this:

```
find . | egrep -v ".old|.obsolete|.~|.wmv|.pyc|.done|.lock|.svn" | xargs svn add --non-recursive
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) option

Comment: Not "option" but rather a "property".